# Why there is swelling when skin doesn't break visibly?

Tags: immunology, immune-system, skin

I had read that swelling occurs as result of blood vessels pouring watery fluid in the affected area to help in fighting the incoming pathogens, when we our skin is cut open. However sometimes like stubbing toe, or getting hit in head, our skin doesnt breaks, but still swelling occurs on the affected region. Whats the point of swelling in that case, when pathogens obviusly are not invading, as our skin is not cut open?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details. (NB: A causes B, does **not** imply there can't be a C also causing B.)